# Joining order in Distributed Database

Tags: distributed-database

I am nowadays trying to study about query optimization in replicated distributed database system. But I got myself confused about joining order of the relations.

If a query execution path is
 `[15E,4F,6I,8B,14D,11G,16J,9H,6A,13C] or [1I,7D,8G,6A,15C,12B,7E,12H,9J,3F]` where every element is composed of a site number where the relation is resided. Then, does the result vary from each other?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand your question. But in general, if you change the order of joining different fragments of tables, each involves it's own cost. I mean, **the cost involved in completing the join will change but not the result**.